# How to do binary decimal calculations with bin2dec

Tags: octave

What is the Octave NaN for? Is dot wrong delimiter?

```
>> bin2dec ('10.1')
ans = NaN
```

Comment: So you want to convert from DEC/VAX formatted floating point binary string to a decimal?

Comment: There is no correct delimiter for what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nan means **[Not a Number](http://wiki.octave.org/wiki.pl?NaN)**

You operation produced an undefined result. *bin2dec(s)* returns the decimal representation of the binary number in *s*. But you passed a decimal number.

You probably wanted to use **[dec2bin()](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/octave3/octave_49.html)**

Comment: I meant by 10.1 a binary number 2^1 + 2^-1 in DEC, not decimal.

Comment: I understand you question Masi. But you cannot use fractional binary representation with dec2bin or bin2dec. As far as I know Octave doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

Those functions only work with integers.

Answer (score 1):

According to Octave's manual, you can [open](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Opening-and-Closing-Files.html) and [read](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Binary-I_002fO.html) binary floating point data in VAX D and VAX G floating format, but 'Conversions are currently only supported for "ieee-be" and "ieee-le" formats.'